# How to get <? tags from xml with vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, xelement

I am extracting some xml files into a database using vb.net but i am having trouble to identify a line in the xml tag with

The xml looks like that:

```
<article type="article">
   <id>0103-0002-004</id>
   <?article zz="3100222857"?>
</article>
```

I am using:

```
Dim articles As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = docIssues...<article>
For Each article As XElement In articles
   strIdXML = article.Element("id")
   strIdXML = IIf(strIdXML Is Nothing, "element does not exist", strIdXML)

   strGaleId = article.Element("ariticle")
   strGaleId = IIf(strGaleId Is Nothing, "element does not exist", strGaleId)
next
```

It is fine with the id but i can't manage to get this

Any clues?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure having `<?` tags in the middle of XML file is valid spec? I've never seen an XML with such tags in it. They usually appear at the top and indicate the header of an XML document.

Comment: That's not an element - it's a processing instruction. No idea how you extract one via `XElement` at the moment though.

Comment: Thanks to @Damien, I found some useful docs. According to MSDN, XDocument supports [processing instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.xml.linq.xprocessinginstruction.aspx), using [XProcessingInstruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.xml.linq.xprocessinginstruction.aspx) class. I never worked with it, so you may need to do some more research for the actual usage/examples. Official spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/, `2.6 Processing Instructions`.

Comment: I never saw this kind of php tag inside an xml structure idem.  I think that if is not a proper marker probably I will have to grab all article element and then search for the <? tag with plain vb functions....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an element, so accessing it via the `Element()` function seems wrong. I *think* that something like:

```
Dim articlePI = article.DescendantNodes()
  .SingleOrDefault(
       Function(node)
         If Typeof node is XProcessingInstruction
           Dim pi = DirectCast(node,XProcessingInstruction)
           Return pi.Target = "article"
         End If
         Return False
       End Function
  )
```

to extract the item. You'd then want to cast it to `XProcessingInstruction` to access it's `Data`.

Comment: Worth making a FOR loop I think, or a separate function. But yeah, something along these lines. +1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use XPath. The XPath command to get a processing instruction is [`processing-instruction()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction).

So, to get the `<?article?>` instruction, you can use*

```
Dim result = doc.SelectSingleNode("article/processing-instruction('article')")
```

<sub>* where `doc` is a `XmlDocument` for convenience. If you want to stick with `XElement`, you'll have to use `CType(xml.XPathEvaluate("processing-instruction('article')"), IEnumerable).OfType(Of XProcessingInstruction)().First()`</sub>